# Sendmail with multiple domain names

Tags: php, email, smtp, centos, sendmail

So I have a server with one domain name, lets say domain1.com. On that same server I have a subserver with another domain name, lets say domain2.com. They both have the same IP address. My server is CentOS and uses sendmail as the SMTP server. Whenever I send emails from domain2.com it still sends it from domain1.com. Is there any way to configure sendmail to send the emails through domain2.com?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to [configure sendmail to use a virtual user/generics table](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/configure-it-quick-set-up-sendmail-to-host-multiple-domains/5033970).